# Averaging speeds

Tags: physics, average, means

I read the answer to this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34794664/how-should-i-calculate-the-average-speed-by-road-segment-for-multiple-segments/34795821#34795821

Can anyone please explain why the harmonic mean is in use when averaging speed and not the "regular average" ?

Comment: Look at the examples section of the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean) page.

Comment: Have you followed the link to [the Wikipedia article provided there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean#In_physics), and read it already?